# Direct proof that the irrationals on $[0,1]$ have measure $1$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am seeking a “direct” proof that the Lebesgue measure of the irrationals on the unit interval is $1$.  The standard proof I see is that the measure of the unit interval is 1, and the rationals have $0$ measure, so the irrationals must have measure $1$.

That is a perfectly good proof, but if we didn’t know the rationals have $0$ measure, is there a “direct” proof that the irrationals have measure $1$?

Comment: I'm not trying to be snarky, but what type of proof do you have in mind? This seems like the simplest proof. If I didn't know the rationals where measure $0$, I would just prove the rationals where measure $0$ and then complete the proof.

Comment: I think it's an interesting question, because you learn less doing the "easy" proof than exploring other avenues. Just my opinion..

Comment: Irrationals are by definition real numbers which are not rational. So, either explicitly or implicitly, the property of rationals must be exploited for the proof. That being said, I suspect that any proof that the set of all irrationals in the unit interval has Lebesgue measure $1$ will involve a form of argument for $\operatorname{Leb}([0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q})=0$ as an intermediate step.

Comment: Remove any one point from the unit interval, and you have (an interval of length 1 or) a union of two intervals of total length 1. If you intersect a countable set of subsets of the unit interval, each of measure 1, you get a set of measure 1. The irrationals are such a set.

Comment: Good question! I was thinking the same. I hope this post gets an answer.